# CSS3 sibling selector hover

Tags: css

I have a problem with css3 and html5. So I decided to make a css effect when hover column div, column icon starts spinning. But i can't do it. So where is my problem?
[http://goo.gl/BLXDF9/](http://goo.gl/BLXDF9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

really simple fix, just remove sibling selector from spin.

```
.column:hover .spin{
    -webkit-animation-name: spin;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: spin;
    -moz-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -ms-animation-name: spin;
    -ms-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;

    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 4000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ymUZj/

Comment: +1 But it's advisable that you post here only the change you did and not the entire code.

Comment: lol, sorry will remember for next time, I'm a bit new :)

Comment: Welcome! You can still edit your answer

Comment: Thank you, it's really simpler than I thought :)

Comment: No worries, don't forget to close the question as well!